# Why is Button not working in tkinter, when i click it it shows an error

Tags: python, tkinter, button, bind

I am trying this code. I want to use don function for `bind()` and `command`. It is showing don() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Event'. how to fix it

my code

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")

def don(Event):
    print("hello")


root.bind("<Return>", don)
btn1 = Button(root, text="check! ", command=don).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since you used same function for `bind()` and `command` option, the `Event` argument of `don()` should be optional, like `def don(Event=None)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is that a function called via `bind` automatically gets an event parameter, but a function called by the `command` option does not. The trick is to make a function that can be called with or without a parameter, and which doesn't use the parameter (since it isn't guaranteed to be there).

The normal way to do this is to make the `event` parameter options, which is done like this:

```
def don(event=None):
    print("hello")
```

This will cause `event` to be set to `None` if it's not passed in, which is harmless since the function doesn't use the `event` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is get rid of Event or as the person said above me Event=None. Depends if you are going to build on it later and add some parameters

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")

def don():
    print("hello")


root.bind("<Return>", don)
btn1 = Button(root, text="check! ", command=don).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Exception will be raised when pressing `Enter` key.